# Should I put my models close together on the build plate, or space them out, to minimise suction?

Tags: resin, build-plate

On a resin printer, if I'm printing 5-6 similarly sized items (Warhammer figures, for example) should I group them close together, or space them far apart, in order to get best adhesion on the build plate and least suction on the FEP?

Answer (score 3):

More is better, as less resin need to come under the build platform during the lift. But very close objects specially for delicate details may cause them bend close together by liquid resin [surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), which will impact surface quality.